# ActionScript 2.0 - Passing numeric data in via Flashvars results in losing zeros

Tags: flash, actionscript, flashvars

I'm modifying someone's old AS 2 Flash application and I need to pass numeric data in as a string OR have a properly formatted USD currency string in the end.

Currently, I might pass something like

```
 Data1=$34,000.00&Data2=$12,344.18&etc...
```

in via FlashVars. Assuming I show Data1 in a dynamic input field, I'd get something like "$34,0"

Any ideas about how to handle this? Honestly, I'm not too concerned whether this is a super clean, proper solution or a functional hack-like solution with this application. It's needed, but only for a short time.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could try encoding the values, so instead of:

```
Data1=$34,000.00&Data2=$12,344.18
```

... you would set the FlashVars to:

```
Data1=%2434%2C000.00&Data2=%2412%2C344.18
```